# Law of Total Probability (Lecture 110 Harvard)

Tags: probability

I was watching Harvard STAT 110 lecture series on Youtube. As per [lecture 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1fSFvhPf7Q), given $$T=X+Y$$ I have the following question:

> Why is $$P(T=t) = \sum P(T=t|X=x)\ P(X=x)$$ and not $$\sum P(T=t|X=x)\ P(X=x)+ \sum P(T=t|Y=y)\ P(Y=y)?$$

Comment: @layman The relation $T=X+Y$ is not relevant in this matter. What follows are "why is..." is also true without that relation. The only things that matter are that $T$ and $X$ must be defined on the same probability space and that $X$ must be discrete.

Comment: @layman Last comment: "...so running through all possible values of $T$ and $X$ is enough..." Enough for what?? It makes no sense at all.

Comment: @layman I don't know what a "stretch" is. Thank you for telling me that you did not downvote me. My comment on your comment concerns the fact that the relation $T=X+Y$ (and all that goes together with it) is completely irrelevant in this situation. $P(T=t)=\sum_xP(T=t\mid X=x)P(X=x)$ is **always** true under the conditions that I mentioned. Let me say (more careful) that your comment makes no sense **to me** then.

Comment: @layman While what you've said is true (the value of $Y$ is determined by the values of $T$ and $X$), it is irrelevant to the question. So presenting it as an explanation here is extremely misleading.

Comment: @layman I'm sorry, but you're wrong. drhab has explained the situation perfectly.

Comment: @AlexKruckman maybe I'm giving a charitable interpretation, but layman's comment seems to say exactly what quasi's answer below says.

Comment: @Tyberius Maybe prior to quasi's edit in response to my comment?

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that X + Y is a sum of the values, not the probabilities? There are two completely different types of numbers in these expressions, which can be confusing to a beginner.

Answer (score 8):

Presumably you meant $T=X+Y$, not $Y=X+Y$.

The cases for $X$ are exhaustive, since $X$ must take *some* value.

Analogously, the cases for $Y$ are exhaustive.

Thus, if you case it by values of $X$, you get
$$P(T=t) = \sum P(T=t|X=x)\,P(X=x)$$ 
and if you case it by values of $Y$, you get
$$P(T=t) = \sum P(T=t|Y=y)\,P(Y=y)$$
but if you sum both, you would get twice the correct answer.

Comment: I like this answer, except for the word "since". The cases for $X$ are exhaustive because we're summing over all possible values of $X$! The fact that $T = X+Y$ is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: I agree. I'll edit to reflect that idea.

Comment: +1 Now it is the time for upvoting. Nice answer!

Comment: @layman: Some value of $X$ must happen, so that already exhausts all cases, regardless of whether or not the value of $Y$ is forced. Similarly, the cases could be based on $Y$, or even something else, as long as the cases are exhaustive and mutually exclusive. So _either_ of the two sums gives the total probability for a given value of $T$, hence, summing _both_ would yield twice the correct result.

Comment: No, the sum
$$\sum_{x,y} P(T=t|X=x, Y=y)\,P(X=x, Y=y)$$
is not double summing. Double summing is what the OP tried to propose, namely
$$\sum P(T=t|X=x)\ P(X=x)+ \sum P(T=t|Y=y)\ P(Y=y)$$
and my answer explains why that would be twice the correct result.

Comment: @layman: It really _isn't_ double summing. As an example, let the experiment be the rolling two standard dice. Let $X$ be the value of the first die, let $Y$ be the value of the second die, and let $T=X+Y$. Then we have
$$P(T=5) = \sum P(T=5|X=x)\,P(X=x)$$
and
$$P(T=5) = \sum P(T=5|Y=y)\,P(Y=y)$$
but we _also_ have
$$P(T=5)=\sum_{x,y} P(T=5|X=x, Y=y)\,P(X=x, Y=y)$$

Comment: @layman: For the dice example, test the claim
$$P(T=5)=\sum_{x,y} P(T=5|X=x, Y=y)\,P(X=x, Y=y)$$
Note that for each of the $36$ summands in the above sum, we always have 
$$P(X=x, Y=y) =\frac{1}{36}$$
and the factor
$$P(T=5|X=x, Y=y)$$
is either $1$ or $0$, according as $x+y=5$ or $x+y\ne 5$.

Comment: @layman "that means that you have the same terms being added twice..." No! As quasi made perfectly clear the only effect is that there are more terms and that lots of them take value $0$. The outcome is not affected. I hope that you are convinced now. I would not say that you are going crazy, but just that you bothered by a blind spot. It happens to me on regular basis.

Comment: @drhab you’re right, it was a blind spot.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $T=X+Y$
so when $T=t,X=x$ you have $Y=t-x$, in other words,
\begin{align}
P(T=t)& = \sum_{x} \left[{P(T=t|X=x)\cdot P(X=x)}\right]\\
&=\sum_{x} \left[{P(X+Y=t|X=x)\cdot P(X=x)}\right]\\
&=\sum_{x} \left[{P(Y=t-x|X=x)\cdot P(X=x)}\right]
\end{align}
which means you have already unknowingly taken $Y$ into account!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$: $$\{T=t\}=\bigcup_x\{T=t\wedge X=x\}=\bigcup_y\{T=t\wedge Y=y\}$$ where $x$ ranges over all values that are taken by $X$ and $y$ over all values that are taken by $Y$.

Then:
$$\sum_x P(T=t\mid X=x)P(X=x)+\sum_y P(T=t\mid Y=y)P(Y=y)=$$$$\sum_x P(T=t\wedge X=x)+\sum_y P(T=t\wedge Y=y)=P(T=t)+P(T=t)=2P(T=t)$$

Comment: Explain the downvote please.

Comment: I didn't vote but I supposed it's partly because the notation you used too. I don't even know how to interpret some and the OP seems to be at a very early stage of learning probability & stats...

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Thank you for your reaction. Could you tell me what in my notation is unclear for you (so that I can take that into account in my later answers to questions)?

Comment: It's not unclear actually. More like it's something students early in stats course wouldn't have seen or be able to read, but after looking them up then it's fine e.g. the big caps and the wedges. (I only just finished A-level a few months ago)

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Thank you and the best wishes for your study of probability.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you for editing and repairing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@quasi's answer is an excellent rigorous answer, but if you'd like a more intuitive way to look at it:

Suppose you want to get to a street corner that is north-east of your current location. You can either go one block north and one block east *or* go one block east and then one block north, but if you do both of them you'll overshoot your target. I.e. you can use either of the two sums and be valid, but you can't do both (i.e. add them together).